# what actually is ran through the query

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

how can I debug a query that it what its going to run,
like
`$this->Article->find('all',array('id'=>123));` is probably running something like

`select * from articles where article.id = 123;` but how can I be sure and can see that in a debug or something.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `app/core/config.php debug = 2`

http://book.cakephp.org/view/924/The-Configuration-Class#CakePHP-Core-Configuration-Variables-931

Answer (score 0):

@Ken's answer is correct, but I would recommend you downloading the [debug_kit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) plugin; as it provides far more information than the standard output.

You will need to enable debug, as stated in the other answer; but the plugin adds a whole host of extras such as logging, performance, full SQL queries, history, variable dumps etc - definitely makes things easier for testing and general debugging.